# Eclipse cannot import package which is defined as dependency in maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, import, maven-eclipse-plugin

I have checked out a maven project into eclipse using subclipse.

I try to use the spring framework in my project, and have defined it as a required dependency:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```

I have added the maven repo by adding the M2_REPO to my CLASS_PATH. I did that by executing this command on the cmd prompt:

```
mvn -Declipse.workspace="your Eclipse Workspace" eclipse:configure-workspace
```

I verified in Eclipse preferences that the M2_REPO variable is in my Classpath variable, and that the path refers to the repository directory of Maven.

However, a import statement like this:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
```

does not work.

What can be the problem here?

EDIT:

Since this was a module under the root, i figured that i did not need to define the dependency on Spring once more in this module. However, including (copy paste the list from the root :s) solved the issue. But this can't be right since the POM.xml in the root already requieres that this module is included.

Comment: If you're using `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and `mvn eclipse:configure-workspace`, the m2eclipse tag is inappropriate. You should use maven-eclipse-plugin or m2eclipse. It doesn't make any sense to use them together.

Comment: In fact, there is no more reason to use the maven-eclipse-plugin at all, now that m2e is a top-level eclipse project

Comment: Ok sorry about that, but would also have an idea about whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding M2_REPO to your class path variables in eclipse if you are not using m2eclipse and mvn eclipse:configure-workspace didn't work..

> Windows-> Preferences ->  Java -> Build Path ->  ClassPath Variables
>   -> new -> M2_REPO or MAVEN_REPO and your Repo location